# How to control LED monitor (desktop) brightness and contrast through an program in UBUNTU 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there any application available which can control LED Monitor (desktop) brightness and contrast? Ideally, it should be configurable and can be made to adjust with day-night settings according to system current time? Or it should have configurable profiles which can be used as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

With the current technology, no. Both vga and dvi (im assuming thats what you are using) do not have a "brightness pin" that can control the backlight of your monitor.